# Why does the emf of a cell not change even if it is being charged

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current

When we charge or discharge a cell, my teacher said that the cell's emf does not change, but why is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't true that the EMF of a battery doesn't change as it is charging and discharging, but it is true that it doesn't change very much.

A battery is effectively an electron pump. If you think about a water pump then what a water pump does is raise the pressure of the water. Water flows in at a low pressure and water flows out at a high pressure. The pressure change depends on the mechanical details of the pump.

In an electrical circuit the *pressure* is the electrical potential, so in a battery electrons flow in at low potential and flow out at high potential. The potential difference is caused by a type of chemical reaction in the battery called a [redox reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redox). Redox reactions pump electrons in an analogous way to the way the impeller in a water pumps the water.

So the EMF of a battery depends on the reaction that takes place inside the battery, and since it's a fundamental property of the reaction it is constant. Well, nearly. As the reaction takes place in the battery the internal resistance of the battery can change slightly and as the concentration of the reagents in the battery changes the reaction potential can change slightly. Both of these will slightly change the EMF you measure when you connect your voltmeter to the battery.

Answer (score 0):

as an "ideal" battery is being discharged, an electrochemical reaction is taking place inside it and in that process, electrons are caused to flow through an external circuit and the active materials that compose the battery are consumed. since the voltage generated by the electrochemical reaction is determined by the nature of the active materials and not by the quantity of each which is present, the battery will generate a constant voltage until it reaches the point of discharge, where all the active materials are spent, and then the voltage falls to zero. the same argument also applies in reverse, for the case of charging the battery back up again. This is a simplified picture; real treatment of this question would require some chemistry!

Answer (score 0):

My personal experience of different types of rechargeable batteries over many years and my design projects for sophisticated charging systems including an early discrete component design of a "negative delta V" type of charger for NiCd cells, leads me to answer your question directly: It is not the case that a cell under charge doesn't change its EMF - it does.  In addition to changes in EMF due to cell chemical changes taking place, thermal considerations somewhat dependent on the rate of charge will also have a bearing on changes in EMF as measured at the cell terminals.

In terms of discharge, the cell EMF can vary during discharge, but any variance depends very much on the type of cell under discussion.  eg, rechargeable Ni-Cd cells will hold their terminal voltage rather well until almost the "last Gasp" of the charge, but a primary carbon-zinc cell (admittedly a non-rechargeable type) gradually reduces its terminal EMF over its usage life.

I suggest that the premise in your question is incorrect, as judged by my humble but long real-world experience.  Is it possible, with great respect, that you misheard your teacher?

Comment: Sir.If battery would be ideal then will emf would change?

Comment: Pranjal, talk of "ideal" batteries shifts discussion from practical physics to philosophy. So, is the teacher who told you that a philosophy or physics teacher? If philosophy then I concede that yes, an ideal battery would have constant EMF at the terminals - because we decided that was ideal!  If a physics teacher told you, then such perfect batteries do not exist.  I'd worry if a real battery had unchanging EMF in all conditions of use. That would be evidence of possibly catastrophic breakdown from necessarily slightly unstable, "positive feedback" type of loops with real-world reactants

Comment: I am not saying that discussion of a theoretical perfection, or ideals, is a bad thing - far from it.  You should indeed discuss ideal situations and artifacts if that will be a help with your career path.  My own career path was a simpler one in that I applied myself to what actually did do useful things, with reliability, for the practical benefit of people, a completely different "philosophy" on my part. I will happily stand aside now and let others take up the discussion with you.  Best wishes to you.